# With MVC, asp.net, is it possible to create a row with URL Query String?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For instance, I'd like to be able to send my.url/movie?title="a"&rating="b" and create a new row in the movie table with the appropriate data.

Is this possible?

One method I've attempted is creating movie.aspx which has movie.aspx.cs and movie.cs as well which can parse the information. Could I then send a post request with the relevant information, maybe?

I'm incredibly new to asp.net, mvc, and c#.

Comment: Yes, check article on [one-click attacks/CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) to know details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly, in the controller that is fired with the example URL, build a handler for `Movie` that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Movie(string title, string rating)
{
    // do your work here

    return View("SomeViewHere");
}
```

where `SomeViewHere` is the view you want to redirect to when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as [Michael Perrenoud mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16971504/2420979), but I would **strongly** recommend against it. This opens you up to all kinds of attacks, including memory attacks where a malicious user could just hit permutations of words in your URL to pollute your database with millions and millions of rows in an effort to make it crash due to running out of space. I would highly recommend against this in any public-facing environment.